# allocate more memory to a GUI process on red hat

Tags: java, user-interface, memory, bin, xming

This is really specific and I searched everywhere for an answer. This is my last ditch effort before I just wait an eternity for this GUI to run.

I installed xming on my computer and I'm running a GUI for TeamSite through a bin file called: IWOVInstaller-Linux-8.1.0.0.0.bin

I did a ps aux | to see how this sucker is running (considering it unpacks the JRE and doesn't require java or JRE to be installed to run) and I come up with the following:

```
tmp/install.dir.17076/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java -Xss1024K -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=33333 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.managemen
t.jmxremote.ssl=false com.zerog.lax.LAX /tmp/install.dir.17076/temp.lax /tmp/env.properties.17076
```

As you can see it seems to be unpacking a version of JRE and running it at 1M worth of memory. All I'm trying to do is bump that number up so it's more responsive as it's painfully slow right now.

Any help regarding this would be *greatly* appreciated.

Thanks!

Joe

Comment: Have you tried `kill -9` on the process and relaunching with  `-Xss` changed?

Comment: @flkes How do you mean? I launch the process as an executable (./IWOVInstaller-Linux-8.1.0.0.0.bin) and it runs the GUI... how would I run it with -Xss changed? Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to do this,.. launch the bin, then get its process id using `ps -ef | grep java` or something similar. Then kill the process using `kill -9 <pid>` and relaunch it with the same command, but the `-Xss` is changed:  `tmp/install.dir.17076/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java -Xss1024M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=33333 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.managemen
t.jmxremote.ssl=false com.zerog.lax.LAX /tmp/install.dir.17076/temp.lax /tmp/env.properties.17076`